# Is a pure subgroup of divisible group also divisible?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Is this true that a pure subgroup of divisible group is also divisible?

Comment: The statement of your question itself would make a better title, even if it looks strange to have the statement just repeat the title.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks for the advice. I made it a bit better.

Answer (score 5):

This follows directly from the definitions.  A group $G$ is divisible if ever element has an $n$th root for every $n$.  A subgroup is $H$ pure if, whenever an element of $H$ has an $n$th root in $G$, it has one in $H$.  So let $H$ be a pure subgroup of a divisible group $G$.  Given any $h\in H$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $h$ has an $n$th root in $G$, and hence in $H$.  Since this holds for every $h$ and $n$, every element of $H$ is divisible in $H$.